# Вывести дерево категорий, но с неограниченной вложенностью

Tags: php, массивы

Код

```
$shop_categories = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Компьютеры',
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Ноутбуки',
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Моноблоки',
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Системные блоки',
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'title' => 'Tower',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'title' => 'Mini Tower',
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Бытовая техника',
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Пылесосы',
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Холодильники',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Выводим дерево:

```
function drevo($shop_categories) {
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ($shop_categories as $key){

      echo "<li>" . $key['title'] . "</li>" ; 

       if (isset($key['children'])){

            drevo($key['children']);
        }

    }

echo '</ul>';

}
drevo($shop_categories);
```

Но если у нас неограниченная вложенность, то такое

```
if (isset($key['children'])){

            drevo($key['children']);
        }
```

уже не прокатит. Как же сделать для неогранич. числа подкаталогов?

Comment: [гляньте тут](http://cyberforum.ru/php-beginners/thread1711595.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас внешний и внутренние массивы разного типа. Рабочий код будет примерно таким:

```
function drevo($shop_category) {
    echo '<ul>';
    echo "<li>" . $shop_category['title'] . "</li>" ; 
    if (isset($shop_category['children'])){
        trees($shop_category['children']);
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
function trees($categories) {
    echo '<ul>';
    for($i = 0; $i < count($categories); $i++) {
        drevo($categories[$i]);
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
trees($shop_categories);
```

Comment: как же drevo без изменений, если там это if (isset($key['children'])){

            drevo($key['children']);
        } не подходит. Так как это условие только для одной вложенной категории..Или вы имели ввиду другое? Можете выложить?

Comment: Я подставил в ваш код свою функцию и не сработало. Можно выложить весь последовательно код реализации?

Comment: Исправил код, не доглядел, что у вас внутри опять обычные массивы. Бтв, думаю, правильнее было бы это все засунуть в одну функцию.